# JQuery - access elements loaded with .ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, dom

I am loading data into

```
<div id="content_8">
</div>
```

using the following function:

```
...
var number = 8; //i.e.
$.ajax
({
    url: "load.inc.php",
    dataTypeString:"html",
    data: "var="+number,
    success: function(html)
    {
        $('#content_'+number).html(html);
    }
});
```

This works well, but: the html contains different IDs and the loaded html looks like for example

```
<tr id="someid_8_1234">...</tr>
<tr id="someid_8_7294">...</tr>
<tr id="someid_8_9999">...</tr>
```

Since they are not yet registered in the DOM, I can't use this code

```
$('[id^=someid_]').click(function(){
    $(this).toggle();
});
```

I am getting crazy, all hints I found so far point me to delegate() or live() which I don't understand and they mostly point to single examples but not to hundreds of IDs, is there a way to attach the whole HTML-Block in the DOM?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: If you're using `$(document).ready(function() {...}` they should be in the DOM.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

use this for dynamcically created elements:

```
$(document).on('click','[id^=someid_]',function()
{
///your code

});
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, thats the solution!

Answer (score 1):

Maybe ...

```
     success: function(html)    {
            var newContent = $.parseHTML(html)
            $('#content_'+number).html(newContent);
            $('[id^=someid_]', newContent).click(function(){
                $(this).toggle();
            });
        }
```

Comment: Yes! This is working as well as $(document).on, thank you!